# list file names from a folder to a tkinter window, with python 3

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

i have the following problem:
i would like to list all filenames from a folder to a tkinter window + a checkbox (with a unique variable) near each filename.
so far i have this:

```
import tkinter as tk

def gui():
    master=tk.Tk()
    files=next(os.walk('forms'))[2]
    i=1
    for f in files:
        'unique var name??'=tk.IntVar()
        tk.Checkbutton(master, text=f, variable='unique var name??').grid(row=i)
    master.mainloop()


gui()
```

this code works, but returns only the last file name from the respective folder + a checkbox in the tkinter window. i don't know how to define a unique tk.IntVar() variable for every checkbox and how to make the master.mainloop() window list all file names. i use python 3.4 on win 7.

thank you in advance!

Comment: Why don't you use a list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need unique variable *names*, you only need unique variables. A list or dictionary works great. Since you're associating the variables with filenames, a dictionary with the filename as a key makes sense:

```
vars = {}
for f in files:
    var = tk.IntVar()
    tk.Checkbutton(master, text=f, variable=var).grid(row=i)
    vars[f] = var
```

Later, to print the value of all the variables, just iterate over the dictionary:

```
for (name, var) in vars.iteritems():
    print(name, var.get())
```

BTW: you have a bug in your code, in that you never increment the row number. You end up stacking all of the buttons on top of each other in the same row. You need to add something like `i += 1` inside your loop.

Comment: thank you for the rapid answer! the dict was a great idea. however, i still can't figure out, how to list on a tkinter window the filenames+checkboxes.

Comment: @WanekT: I updated my answer to address the bug that causes most of the checkbuttons to be invisible.

Comment: wow, what a shame for me... i did not observed until you mentioned. now, it looks good. thanks again, you saved my day!  maybe i'm too tired.